# How to start an existing docker container with displaying the output?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

When we run a new docker container using `docker run` command we can see the output of the containing service. But when we use `docker start` to start the same container when it is stopped, it prints just the name of the container, not the output.

How can I start a stopped container with displaying the output?

Example:

*docker run*

```sh
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --name tomcat_daemon tomcat:latest
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.53
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.750 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 11 2020 10:01:39 UTC
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.53.0
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.752 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.753 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.19.76-linuxkit
26-Apr-2020 06:03:27.754 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
...
```

*docker start*

```sh
$ docker start tomcat_daemon
tomcat_daemon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `docker start -i my_container`

```
--interactive , -i      Attach container’s STDIN
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/